# LoadLibraryExW Fails to Load User32.dll

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

When trying to load C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll via LoadLibraryExW, it fails with the last error of ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH.

Here is how it is loaded:

```
HMODULE User32Lib = LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\user32.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_REQUIRE_SIGNED_TARGET);
```

I looked at the DLL itself, and it was signed (for the version on my machine) on 8 April 2020 so it should still be valid.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Does it load properly if you call it without the `LOAD_LIBRARY_REQUIRE_SIGNED_TARGET` flag?

Comment: It loads properly without that flag.

Comment: Hmm.Any chance it's a 32-bit executable trying to load a 64-bit dll ?

Comment: No, the executable is a 64-bit executable.

Comment: This is strange; does the same thing on my 64-bit Win10 machine. No idea what's going on...

Comment: @ErykSun that seems to be the case. Can you make that an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: `/integritycheck` was the key, I was able to find other places (including on MS sites), where that was confirmed.

Comment: @ErykSun - you should definitely answer. This is also discussed here as you probably found out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/95e032d8-de23-47a8-a6e7-858a2b2b731f/how-exactly-sign-dlls-for-appinitdlls-?forum=windowssecurity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently `LOAD_LIBRARY_REQUIRE_SIGNED_TARGET` requires the PE image to be linked with `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY` (0x0080) in its [DLL characteristics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header64). This is a flag that forces the memory manager in the kernel to check for a digital signature when loading the image. Refer to the linker option [/INTEGRITYCHECK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/integritycheck-require-signature-check?view=vs-2019).

Most of the system DLLs do not have this characteristic. "user32.dll" doesn't have it, but "bcrypt.dll" does:

```bsh
PS C:\> $user32_hdr = get-peheader C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll
PS C:\> $bcrypt_hdr = get-peheader C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
PS C:\> '{0:x}' -f $user32_hdr.DllCharacteristics
4160
PS C:\> '{0:x}' -f $bcrypt_hdr.DllCharacteristics
41E0
```

---

I don't know much in particular about the subject of code signing and the implementation details in the loader and memory manager. I just used a debugger to discover that the load was failing with `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH` in `LdrpCompleteMapModule`, after it checked for 0x80 in the DLL characteristics. From there I searched for discussions on this value and the `/integritycheck` option in relation to `LOAD_LIBRARY_REQUIRE_SIGNED_TARGET`. I found a few unofficial references that claimed the latter requires the former. So I wrote a script to dump the DLL characteristics of system DLLs in order to find one that has the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY` flag. Having found "bcrypt.dll" and checked that it wasn't already loaded, I confirmed that loading it with `LOAD_LIBRARY_REQUIRE_SIGNED_TARGET` does work.